# how to create large tables with redundancy without elt tools

Tags: mysql, database, performance, elasticsearch

Because query params, we have multiple SQLs has multiple table joins. Current, we want to create a set large tables in elasticsearch or mysql with all needs columns for every SQL.We looked for a long time but only found ELT Tools and Materialized Views.We wanted to ask if there was another way to do that.
Our raw data is stored in mysql.

Comment: "Redundancy" -- Every data item shows up in multiple tables?  Summary tables?  What do you mean?  I suggest that you pick one example for us to discuss.

Comment: like this TableA(id,tableBid,aname,) TableB(id,bname),TableC(id,tableAid,name) then gen TableRedundancy(tableAid,aname,tableBid,bname,tableCid,tableCname)

Comment: That sounds like non-redundant data.  Add to your question some more specific information about the data.  It may also be helpful the give us a flavor for the data -- sensors / products / people / climate / history / what?